# Angular 2 ElementRef nativeElement offsetWidth always 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get the width of an element that has a dynamic width, I can get the width with pure javascript but not Angular 2.

```js
constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
// ....
```

getting the width

```js
let width =  this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth;

console.log('js offset width', document.getElementById('foobar').offsetWidth);
console.log('angular2 offset width', width);
```

This works fine:

```js
document.getElementById('foobar').offsetWidth
```

But not angular 2's width, it's always 0. So how can I get the offset width via Angular's ElementRef?

Comment: You can try `console.dir(this.element.nativeElement)` and `console.dir(document.getElementById('foobar'))`, to see if they both refer to the same element.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444862/angular-2-elementref-nativeelement-offsetwidth-returning-same-value-even-when

Answer (score 0):

You are not associating the `TemplateRef` with any of the DOM element

```
@ViewChild('foo') foo: TemplateRef;
```

Have the attribute in HTML  as

```
 <div #foo></div>
```

Now OnInit try to get the value it will be a non zero.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1w96WHDQ0HgEklEFNdEg)**

Comment: my code is in a component,  shouldn't I be using ElementRef in the constructor?